# Total and partial derivatives

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative, chain-rule

I have a function $Y(x,t)$ and another function $\eta(x,t)$.

I have the total derivative $\dfrac{dY}{d\eta}$.

So, what is the correct?

$$\dfrac{dY}{d\eta}\dfrac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial Y}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \eta}\dfrac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial Y}{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial t}{\partial \eta}\dfrac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}=\dfrac{2\partial Y}{\partial x}$$

or

$$\dfrac{dY}{d\eta}\dfrac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial Y}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \eta}\dfrac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial Y}{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial t}{\partial \eta}\dfrac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial Y}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial Y}{\partial t}\underbrace{\dfrac{\partial t}{\partial x}}_{0}=\dfrac{\partial Y}{\partial x}$$

?

Thank you so much.

Comment: $$\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}u}=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\frac{\mathrm{d}x_i}{\mathrm{d}u}$$

Comment: Do you mean that I might write $\dfrac{d x}{d \eta}$ instead of $\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial \eta}$? Thank you @K.defaoite

Comment: I'll illustrate in an answer.

Comment: OK, Thank you @K.defaoite

Answer (score 2):

In the described situation there is no such thing as ${dY\over d\eta}$.

When $$Y: \quad(x,t)\mapsto Y(x,t),\qquad \eta:\quad (x,t)\mapsto\eta(x,t)$$
are two real valued functions defined in the $(x,t)$-plane, and a point $(x_0,t_0)$ is given, then the gradients of $Y$ and $\eta$ at $(x_0,t_0)$ determine the increments of $Y$ and $\eta$ when moving away from $(x_0,t_0)$:
$$\eqalign{\Delta Y&=\nabla Y(x_0,t_0)\cdot(\Delta x,\Delta t)+o\bigl(\sqrt{\Delta x^2+\Delta t^2}\bigr),\cr
\Delta \eta&=\nabla \eta(x_0,t_0)\cdot(\Delta x,\Delta t)+o\bigl(\sqrt{\Delta x^2+\Delta t^2}\bigr)\ .\cr}$$
It follows that $\Delta Y$ and $\Delta\eta$ depend on the *direction* of the increment vector $(\Delta x,\Delta t)$. The same is true for the quotient ${\Delta Y\over\Delta\eta}$ and its limit (called ${dY\over d\eta}$ by you), when $\sqrt{\Delta x^2+\Delta t^2}\to0$.

It is another thing when $x$ and $t$ are not independent variables, and $x$ is in fact a function of $t$, given as $x=\psi(t)$. In this case $Y$ and $\eta$ also become composed functions of $t$:
$$\hat Y(t):=Y\bigl(\psi(t),t\bigr),\qquad \hat \eta(t):=\eta\bigl(\psi(t),t\bigr)\ .$$
In this case it makes sense to talk about $${d\hat Y\over d\hat\eta}={\hat Y'(t)\over\hat\eta'(t)}=\ldots\quad .$$

Comment: thank you so much. In fact I have $\eta=x/t$, this can be seen as a clue or even though there is no sense in writing $dY/d\eta$...? Thanks.

Comment: In fact, I'd like to understand this to could understand this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3919510/homogenous-ode-changing-of-variable. Maybe you could help me. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}Y}{\mathrm{d}\eta}=\frac{\partial Y}{\partial x}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}\eta}+\frac{\partial Y}{\partial t}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}\eta}$$
Now,
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\eta}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial t}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}x}$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\eta}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}+\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial t}$$
Invert these and plug them into the above. This all tends to be much easier when we have some information about $Y,\eta$.

Comment: Thank you! If $t$ and $x$ are independent variables can I zero $dt/dx$ and $dx/dt$? And in this case I have $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}\eta}\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}=1$? Thank you

Comment: @Na'omi Usually you can't do this. Hard to say without more information on the two functions.

Comment: I have $\eta=x/t$, but really haven't information about $Y$. Thank you once again!

Comment: @K. defaoite In fact, I'd like to understand this to could understand this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3919510/homogenous-ode-changing-of-variable. Maybe you could help me. Thanks so much.